# Windows Server 2008r2 scheduled backup to NAS breaks on 3 of 4 identical servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-attached-storage, windows-server-backup

I have 4 identical Windows server 2008R2 installs, all uptodate. 
Initially I had 4 scheduled backups to a Windows share on a NAS, running nightly, all work OK.  Then 2 of the backups would not complete.  Then 3 would not complete. This was over the space of a year or two.  Redoing the schedule, the login to the NAS server fails.  BUT I can do manual backups using same NAS login just fine! (that is how I have to do the backups now).  I tried the command line wbadmin and it fails too!!   What in the world broke? Identical servers, same share, same login.  Thanks. JOhn

Comment: Check logs on both sides and post your findings. I am sure you will find some lower level issues at place. Then change TIME of backups (to another timeslot) to amake sure it is not something time related (like the switch between them making a reset every day at the same hour).

Comment: I have struggled interpreting/setting logs.  Logs of scheduled fails are long gone.  When I try to schedule backup, different times, windows Logs/Apps shows "SQLServerAgent could not be started" and an xinetd prob - but these are common on this machine for some reason?? Apps and Svcs Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Backup shows nothing.  Logs on Buffalo Terraserver NAS don't even show logins/failed - have not figured out how to mod it....  I should wireshark the failing login to get info-somehow key to problem... but smb a pain to interpret.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this article: http://www.wikihow.com/Backup-and-Restore-from-NAS-with-AOMEI-Backupper#Backup_to_NAS_with_AOMEI_Backupper_sub. As to the schedule backup Server, http://www.backup-utility.com/windows-server/automatic-backup-windows-2003.html can help you. This software (server edition) can be applied on Windows Server 2008 R2.